# pandas cut a series with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I would like to apply the pandas cut function to a series that includes NaNs. The desired behavior is that it buckets the non-NaN elements and returns NaN for the NaN-elements.

```
import pandas as pd
numbers_with_nan = pd.Series([3,1,2,pd.NaT,3])
numbers_without_nan = numbers_with_nan.dropna()
```

The cutting works fine for the series without NaNs:

```
pd.cut(numbers_without_nan, bins=[1,2,3], include_lowest=True)
0      (2.0, 3.0]
1    (0.999, 2.0]
2    (0.999, 2.0]
4      (2.0, 3.0]
```

When I cut the series that contains NaNs, element 3 is correctly returned as NaN, but the last element gets the wrong bin assigned:

```
pd.cut(numbers_with_nan, bins=[1,2,3], include_lowest=True)
0      (2.0, 3.0]
1    (0.999, 2.0]
2    (0.999, 2.0]
3             NaN
4    (0.999, 2.0]
```

How can I get the following output?

```
0      (2.0, 3.0]
1    (0.999, 2.0]
2    (0.999, 2.0]
3             NaN
4      (2.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is strange. The problem isn't `pd.NaT`, it's the fact your series has `object` dtype instead of a regular numeric series, e.g. `float`, `int`.

A quick fix is to replace `pd.NaT` with `np.nan` via `fillna`. This triggers series conversion from `object` to `float64` dtype, and may also lead to better performance.

```
s = pd.Series([3, 1, 2, pd.NaT, 3])

res = pd.cut(s.fillna(np.nan), bins=[1, 2, 3], include_lowest=True)

print(res)

0    (2, 3]
1    [1, 2]
2    [1, 2]
3       NaN
4    (2, 3]
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [[1, 2] < (2, 3]]
```

A more generalized solution is to convert to numeric explicitly beforehand:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
```